# how to insert into auto incerment columns of mysql database?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

> 

I am doing this to insert into a oracle table from set of DTOs.

this is working fine for oracle.

```
List<String> columns = new ArrayList<String>(dashboardDTO.getAttributeMap().keySet());
        String value ="";
        try
        {
            //PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sqlquerry);
string qry1 = "select SURFBI_DASHBOARDS_SEQ.NEXTVAL from DUAL";
            int dashboardID = 0;
            Map<String, String> metadatamap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            metadatamap = getTableMetaData(con, "surfbi_dashboards");
            if(EIInfo.DB_TYPE.equalsIgnoreCase("oracle"))
            {
            dashboardID = getNextID(con, qry1);
            }
            System.out.println(dashboardID);
            //attributemap.get("DASHBOARD_ID")
            /*metadatamap.put("dashboard_id", "NUMBER");
            metadatamap.put("dashboard_title", "Varchar2");*/
            String cols="";
            String vals="";
            for(String column:columns )
            {

                if(metadatamap.containsKey(column)){
                    //true

                    cols=cols+column+",";
                    String dataType=metadatamap.get(column);
                    value = dashboardDTO.getAttributeMap().get(column);

                    if(value==null || value== "")
                    {
                        vals = vals+"null ,";
                    }

                    else if(column== "DASHBOARD_ID" && dataType.equalsIgnoreCase("NUMBER"))
                    {
                        vals=vals+ dashboardID +",";
                    }
                    else if(dataType.equalsIgnoreCase("NUMBER"))
                    {
                        vals=vals+ Integer.parseInt(value)+",";
                    }

                    else if (dataType.equalsIgnoreCase("Varchar2"))
                    {
                        vals=vals+"'"+value+"',";
                    }
                    else if (dataType.equalsIgnoreCase("CLOB"))
                    {
                        vals=vals+"'"+value+"',";
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        vals = vals+"null ,";
                    }
                }
            }
            cols=cols.substring(0, (cols.length()-1));
            vals=vals.substring(0, (vals.length()-1));  
            String sqlquerry = DatabaseQueryGenerator.getInsertQuery("surfbi_dashboards", cols,vals);
            System.out.println(sqlquerry);  

            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            int numbr = st.executeUpdate(sqlquerry);
```

Now my need is to insert same data from the DTOs to MYSQL database, So i tried this and i got the error something like **the table does not exist in the database** because Mysql database does not support the sequences like in oracle so the statement below

```
string qry1 = "select SURFBI_DASHBOARDS_SEQ.NEXTVAL from DUAL";
dashboardID = getNextID(con, qry1);
```

are giving out error.
So i need a solution for this, how can i insert the data into MYSQL database for auto increment columns.
Or shall i need to skip the auto increment columns from inserting into the table, if so how can i skip the specific columns not to insert into the table?

Please Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just an example for an alternate solution

**Mysql table mytable has 3 columns name,age and id**
Suppose id is an auto incremented column

```
insert into mytable(name,age) values('test',1);
```

If you insert these ways then auto incremented fields are incremented automatically.

Just skip the auto incremented column name

Answer (score 1):

Well, if the field is set as auto-increment in Database table, then you don't have to assign any value from your application just leave with null value for it (as Kevin has mentioned).

If your field is not set as auto-increment in Database but you want your application should handle auto-increment then you can do as following:

SELECT MAX(column1)+1 FROM table

[For further information read this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html)

Enjoy exploring!

Answer (score 0):

If the key column is set to `null` the auto numbering in MySql will provide the appropriate value.